# Was/is there such a thing as Yoga Sleep as an initiation ritual?

Tags: rituals

What I would consider an unreliable source (and not a Hindu) wrote about an ancient initiation ritual he called Yoga Sleep that took place in a sepulchre and involved a hierophant taking a pupil into a higher state of consciousness (which left his body lie inert in a kind of deep slumber) for three days where his soul was led through the spheres of the spiritual world.  The pupil was then called 'back into life' by the hierophant where he would utter certain words.  There is more detail but I thought this would do for starters.  I'm not asking if this is possible but if this is something that is recorded as happening in history or even mythology or whether it's someone getting creative with someone else's religion.

Comment: what you've stated is a mish mosh of different unrelated practices and stories that have been rolled up into one untrue story.